# How to load Blob images in angular from phpmyadmin table

Tags: html, angular, database, laravel

I created a function and set a get method to receive all the data from my table.
However I can't display images on browser. I have tried all the "solutions" but nothing seems to work.

This is what I currently have

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let obj of dataArr">
    <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.price}}</td>
    <td>
      <img  src="data:image/png;base64,{{obj.img}}"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Name and price are displayed fine.

This is the data that I receive when I console log:
0: {id: 2, name: "nesto", price: "6", img: "ÿØÿàJFIFÿáExifII*ÿá…"QD¢%(DJ"QD¢%(DJ"QD¢%(DJ"QD¢/ÿÙ"}

Comment: Is the image from your database encoded in base64?

Comment: please post the value of `obj.img`

Comment: @user8555937 It is saved as mediumblob in phpmyadmin

Comment: @NikkoKhresna 0: {id: 2, name: "Nesto", price: "6", img: "ÿØÿàJFIFÿáExifII*ÿá…"QD¢%(DJ"QD¢%(DJ"QD¢%(DJ"QD¢/ÿÙ"}                            This is the format that i recieven image when I console log all data

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{
    btoa(obj.img) /* or window.btoa(obj.img) try both */
}}"/>
```

---

I advise you to create a route which retrieves the file from database:

```
// routes.php

Route::get('files/{record_id}', function($record_id){
    $Model = \EloquentModel::firstOrFail($record_id, ['img']);

    return response($Model->img)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
});

// angular file
<img src="/files/{{ obj.id }}">
```

Comment: When I insert <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{
    base64_encode(obj.img)
}}"/> the base64_encode is not recognized in angular

Comment: I thought you were in blade template. base64_encode is not an Angluar command. You need to output the image from your database in a base64 format because you're trying to display it in browser as a base64 encoded string.

Comment: See my updated answer. If it still doesn't work you need to return the converted image to base64 from your Laravel controller.

Comment: non of those solutions work, is there any other way ?